# Convert JavaScript code to C# to get Frequent Word Count

Tags: javascript, c#

I'm new to c#, I solved this algorithm using Javascript, can anyone help me to convert the below code to c#.

**Details:**

Given an array of words and a number K, return an
array with length K where the ith element of the array
is the number of unique prexes with length i among
the given words (i = 1,2,. . . ,K) (including only words that
are at least i characters long).

**My code:**

```js
function getUniquePrefixCount(words, len) {
 const prefixMap = {};
 words.forEach(word => {
if (word.length >= len) {
 const prefix = word.substr(0, len);
 prefixMap[prefix] = true;
}
 });
 return Object.keys(prefixMap).length;
 }

 function getFrequentWordCount(words, k) {
 return [...Array(k)].map(
(_, i) => getUniquePrefixCount(words, i + 1)
);
 }
```

Comment: Give us an attempt first and show us where you get stuck using C#, Attempt first, you'll learn faster

Comment: The code in the question came straight from [this PDF](https://codesignal.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/javascript-core-assessment-framework.pdf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Another Solution using simple loops**

```js
function getFrequenWordCount(words = [], k)
{
    let myFreuentCount = [];
    for (let index = 1; index <= 8; index++) {
        var setValues = new Set();
        words.forEach(word => {
            myFreuentCount = [];
            if(word  => k){
                const prefix = (word.length >= index ) ? word.substr(0 , index) : '' ;
                if(prefix.length>=1 ){
                    setValues.add(prefix);
                }
            }
       });
       console.log(setValues.size);
    }
}
console.log(getFrequenWordCount(["apple","app","apricot","stone"],8));
```

Comment: How is this the right answer??  The original poster asks for code in C#, and this is still JavaScript

Answer (score 1):

---

### check this code

---

```js
            string[] words = new string[4] { "apple", "app", "apricot", "stone" };
            int[] output = new int[8];
            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
            {
                output[i] = words.GroupBy(s => (s.Length >= i + 1 ? s.Substring(0, i + 1) : string.Empty))
                                 .Select(x => new { x.Key, Count = x.Count() })
                                 .Where(x => x.Key != string.Empty).Count();
                Console.WriteLine(output[i]);
            }
```